# What or who is causing these small poop-like balls of soil below the pot?

Tags: identification, diagnosis

What is this poop-like sand doing in my pot saucer/tray? I saw them today. I lifted the pot(Dracaena Reflexa [Song of India]) and couldn't find a bug or anything. So I thought maybe it's the sand falling from the pot holes, but they are too perfect and makes me wonder if it's really sand falling from the holes or a work of art. But if it is a work of art, then who is the artist?

Also, I crushed some and found them to be sand. The plant is kept in home.

**Click to zoom**:[image]

Comment: Are they approximately the diameter of the drainage holes? (Although I've never seen that happen)

Comment: @J.Musser Nope. They are smaller than the drainage hole.

Comment: Look to be about the size of cockroach poop, but you'd've noticed those, and they don't hang out in pot soil.

Comment: I’ve been suspicious of a coriander plant I just bought. There were little round bits of soil all on my counter. Yesterday I just took out a weevil that was on the wall. This morning I actually saw one of the soil balls jump from the pot. I’ve just put the plant outside. I take it it’s weevils that are causing this?

Comment: Lynne, welcome to Gardening SE! Your post is a bit unclear for me - are you saying “it’s weevils that are causing the things in the picture *in the question above*“ or “I have a similar problem, could this be cause die by weevils”? If it’s the former, please [edit] your post to make it clearer ([answer] should help), if it’s the latter, it’s not an answer. You may always ask a new question, let me encourage you to take the [tour] and browse our [help], especially [ask].

Comment: @LynneHudson The ones in my case don't jump are much like soil.

Answer (score 6):

My hypothesis is that it is worm poop. Also known as worm castings. If there is a lot of sand in the pot that would explain why they break into sand. Here is a picture I found of worm castings from a rich soil: [https://highyieldorganics.net/products/worm-castings](https://web.archive.org/web/20160516090258/https://highyieldorganics.net/products/worm-castings) (URL to archive version)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is right. I see this a lot. OP is probably using garden soil.

Comment: Yes, exactly like this except the color. The one you showed is black I color. The one in my pic is identical to the color of soil.